# as.POSIXct gives inexplicable NA value

Tags: r, datetime

I have a large dataset (21683 records) and I've managed to combine date and time to datetime in a correct way using asPOSIXct. Nevertheless, this did not work for 6 records (17463:17468). This is the dataset I'm using:

```
> head(solar.angle)
        Date     Time sol.elev.angle ID            Datetime
1 2016-11-24 15:00:00       41.32397  1 2016-11-24 15:00:00
2 2016-11-24 15:10:00       39.11225  2 2016-11-24 15:10:00
3 2016-11-24 15:20:00       36.88180  3 2016-11-24 15:20:00
4 2016-11-24 15:30:00       34.63507  4 2016-11-24 15:30:00
5 2016-11-24 15:40:00       32.37418  5 2016-11-24 15:40:00
6 2016-11-24 15:50:00       30.10096  6 2016-11-24 15:50:00

> solar.angle[17460:17470,]
            Date     Time sol.elev.angle    ID            Datetime
17488 2017-03-26 01:30:00      -72.01821 17460 2017-03-26 01:30:00
17489 2017-03-26 01:40:00      -69.53832 17461 2017-03-26 01:40:00
17490 2017-03-26 01:50:00      -67.05409 17462 2017-03-26 01:50:00
17491 2017-03-26 02:00:00      -64.56682 17463                <NA>
17492 2017-03-26 02:10:00      -62.07730 17464                <NA>
17493 2017-03-26 02:20:00      -59.58609 17465                <NA>
17494 2017-03-26 02:30:00      -57.09359 17466                <NA>
17495 2017-03-26 02:40:00      -54.60006 17467                <NA>
17496 2017-03-26 02:50:00      -52.10572 17468                <NA>
17497 2017-03-26 03:00:00      -49.61071 17469 2017-03-26 03:00:00
17498 2017-03-26 03:10:00      -47.11515 17470 2017-03-26 03:10:00
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
solar.angle$Datetime <- as.POSIXct(paste(solar.angle$Date,solar.angle$Time), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

I've already tried to fill them in manually but this did not make any difference:

```
> solar.angle$Datetime[17463] <- as.POSIXct('2017-03-26 02:00:00', format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
> solar.angle$Datetime[17463]
[1] NA
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Daylight saving. Check your time zone.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? The 'time'-part is constantly repeating itself but these are the only records that are giving NA

Comment: These datetimes do not exist in your timezone due to the "lost" hour during the switch to daylight saving time. Maybe use `solar.angle$Datetime <- as.POSIXct(paste(solar.angle$Date,solar.angle$Time), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "GMT")`

Comment: In your second code example the row numbers do not match the ID, _e.g._ row 17491 = ID 17463. Is this as expected? Make sure the index refers to the correct row.

Comment: Thanks @Roland! This was indeed the solution.

Comment: @neilfws Yes this exactly what I want but it seems strange to me that with the call `solar.angle[17460:17470,]` these rows appear (17488:17498) and not the ones you would expect (17460:17470)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that this is the time you switch to summer time, so you need to specify the time zone, otherwise there is ambiguity. 
If you specify a time zone, it will work:

```
as.POSIXct('2017-03-26 02:00:00', format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "GMT")
```

Which returns:
    "2017-03-26 02:00:00 GMT"

You can check `?timezones` for more information.

Comment: Thanks! This clears my problem. I found the time zone name via this link: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones] which was suggest by `?timezones`